# Событие при изменении в базе DataSet

Tags: c#, база-данных

Создал в решении проект где храню DataSet и методы по запросам к базе. Как мне отслеживать изменения в одной таблице и обновлять DataGrid если в базе что-то изменилось?

Answer (score 2):

Смотря каким образом обновляется ваша БД. Если это происходит "по вине" вашего же приложения, то имеет смысл создать событие обновления базы, реализовать для него обработчик, в котором описывать логику обновления содержимого грида, а вызывать событие там, где вы пишете/обновляете/удаляете данные из бд.

Если же база обновляется откуда-то еще, из источников, которые вы не контролируете, либо обновление происходит чересчур интенсивно, то можно запустить отдельный поток, который будет время от времени обращаться к бд, и в случае ее изменения обновлять грид

Ну а если вы используете WPF, то вам в этом может помочь класс [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/dd252944.aspx), у которого есть событие [CollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/vstudio/ms653375(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Работаю с WPF. База может обновляться с других мест кроме клиента, к тому же программа скорее всего многопользовательская будет. Если в кратце то вот как весь процесс у меня происходит.
http://pastebin.com/GZRgjNnp

Comment: тогда обновляйте отдельным потоком, или можете даже создать целую службу, которая будет этим заниматься. Правда, тогда придется шаманить с взаимодействием службы и приложения

Answer (score 2):

Если в общем — никак. Базы данных в классическом понимании не предназначены для таких сценариев, они поддерживают лишь [CRUD-операции](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete).

Тем не менее, некоторые базы данных предоставляют возможность узнать об обновлении через отдельный интерфейс. Вот [пример для SQL Server + Entity Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233770/AutoRefresh-Entity-Framework-data-using-SQL-Server). Общего подхода, работающего со всеми базами данных, я не знаю.

И да, всегда возможен поллинг и трюки с триггерами (например, обновление таблицы может обновлять timestamp в оговоренном месте).

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри [здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.fill(v=vs.110).aspx), может поможет

Comment: и как мне это поможет? это же просто заполнение, я имел в виду событие которое бы сообщало что в базе произошли изменения, и уже сделать запрос и обновить данные в таблице.